# Error at the end of the statement SSRS expression , couldn"t find it?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

```
=
"<b>"+ "Created on: " + "</b>" & CDate(Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_date_create.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")) 
& Environment.NewLine
& "<b>" + "Approval date: " + "</b>" & iif (IsNothing(Fields!date_approval.value),"Not Approved",CDate( Fields!date_approval.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm"))

& Environment.NewLine

& "<b>" + "Solutions: " +"</b>" & Fields!ticket_ticketSolutions_content_plainText.Value
```

### The Value expression for the textrun 'solution_all.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

The definition of the report '' is invalid.

I don't understand where are my errors ?? as I created a calculated fields that contains this formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mis-matching `)`s on line 2 . Remove the end `)`.

Comment: Please remember to mark answers as accepted if they actually answer you question.  You can do this by clicking check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons. I see you have asked 6 questions but not accepted any answers. It's important for other users who want to help so they can see if they need to offer an answer, or for users that are looking for answers to similar questions they can find accepted answers.